# __builtin__ module in Python

Tags: python, module

If I have a module `Test` and if I need to list all the functions in them, I do this:

```
import Test
dir(Test)
```

Unless I import the module I won't be able to use the functions defined in them.

But all the functions in `__builtin__` module can be used without importing. But without `import __builtin__` I am not able to do a `dir(__builtin__)`. Does that mean we use the functions without importing the entire module?

```
from __builtin__ import zip
```

Is it something like the above? But if I do `del zip`, I get

> NameError: name 'zip' is not defined

Can anyone please explain this behavior?

Comment: In CPython, you could do `dir(__builtins__)` without importing anything, but that's an implementation detail of CPython.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in [the Python language docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding), names in Python are resolved by first looking them up in the local scope, then in any enclosing local scope, then in the module-level scope and finally in the namespace of the built-ins.  So built-ins are somehow special-cased.  They are *not* imported in your module's scope, but if a name is not found anywhere else, Python will look it up in the scope `__builtin__`.

Note that you can access the contents of this scope without importing it.  A portable way to do this is

```
import sys
print(dir(sys.modules["__builtin__"]))
```

In CPython, this also works

```
print(dir(__builtins__))
```

but this is considered an implementation detail and might not be available for other Python implementations or future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means knowledgeable about python, but maybe `dir(__builtins__)`, with an "s", is what you're after?

Works for me on plain Python 3.1.

Comment: No. I am talking about `__builtin__` module without an "s". http://docs.python.org/library/__builtin__.html. I am not talking about the `CPython` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

when python interpreter start, it will by default execute something like

`from __builtin__ import *`

which allows you to use all the functions/attributes defined inside `__builtin__` module

However to use `__builtin__` symbol itself, you need to do

import `__builtin__`

this is how import statement syntax works.

Comment: This really helps!  Python 2.6.6