# Where is the __builtin__ module in Python3? Why was it renamed?

Tags: python

I was curious about the `__builtin__` module and how it's used, but I can't find it in Python3!  Why was it moved?

Python 2.7

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>>
```

Python 3.2

```
>>> import __builtin__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named __builtin__
>>>
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The `__builtin__` module was renamed to `builtins` in Python3.

This change solves 2 sources of confusion for the average Python developer.

- Is it `'__builtins__'` or `'__builtin__'` that is in the global namespace?
  Darn s!
- Is `__builtin__` a [special method name](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) or a module?  I can't
  tell.

This confusion mainly arises because of the violation of [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) convention.  Also, the lack of pluralization on the module hinders communication as well.  Both of these are greatly illustrated by the lengths Guido must go to explain the following from http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-March/003821.html:

> [CPython] looks at the globals, which contain a special magic entry
>   `__builtins__` (with an 's') which is the dict where built-in functions are looked up. When this dict is the same object as the *default*
>   built-in dict (which is `__builtin__.__dict__` where `__builtin__` --
>   without 's' -- is the module defining the built-in functions) it gives
>   you supervisor privileges;…

For example,

Python2.7

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> vars(globals()['__builtins__']) is vars(__builtin__)
True
>>>
```

Python3.2

```
>>> import builtins
>>> vars(globals()['__builtins__']) is vars(builtins)
True
>>>
```

**Related resources**:

Other name changes - http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html#name-changes

For a succinct explanation of how `__builtins__` is used in name resolution - [__builtin__ module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325021/builtin-module-in-python)

Comment: How does it solve the builtin vs bultins problem? I can still get it wrong if I'm not sure if there is an s or not

Comment: @blues If you try `import builtin`, an error `ImportError: No module named 'builtin'
` will show up, which is very easy to understand. Moreover, the module is now [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

Answer (score -8):

remove all pyc file and run again
thats all