# What is the default binding to the `__import__` attribute of the module `builtin`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-internals, python-importlib

From Python in a Nutshell

> **Custom Importers**
>
> An advanced, rarely needed functionality that Python offers is the
>   ability to change the semantics of some or all  import  and  from 
>   statements.
>
> **Rebinding __import__**
>
> You can rebind the  `__import__`  attribute of the module  `builtin`
>   to your own custom importer function—for example, one using the
>   generic built-in-wrapping technique shown in “Python built-ins” on
>   page 174.

1. In "You can rebind the  `__import__`  attribute of the module  `builtin`", should "the module  `builtin`" be "the module  `builtins`" instead?
2. Is "the  `__import__`  attribute of the module  `builtin`" [bound to `importlib.__import__`function by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.__import__)? Or does "the module  `builtin`" provide the default implementation bound to its   `__import__`  attribute?

Comment: 1. Yes. That's probably an editing error.

Comment: 2. No. It is bound to `builtins.__import__`. Save that function if you rebind it.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047745/where-is-the-builtin-module-in-python3-why-was-it-renamed) is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, that's a typo in the book. In Python 2 the same module is named [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) (no `s`), in Python 3 it is named [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).
2. `builtins.__import__` is a distinct function from `importlib.__import__`. If you are going to rebind `builtins.__import__`, save a reference.

   - `builtins.__import__` is [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Python/bltinmodule.c#L220-L260), and essentially calls the [C-API `PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject` function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject).
   - `importlib.__import__` is a [pure-Python function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1047-L1079). The *goal* of `importlib` is to provide a pure-python implementation of the import machinery so it can be hacked on more easily, and this function is no exception.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that `importlib.__import__` implement the same things as `builtins.__import__`? The only difference between them is in which language they are implemented?

Comment: @Tim: exactly, the two *aim* to do the same thing.