# Python3: how to import antlr4

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, antlr4

I'm trying to import antlr4 into a python3 code but I obtain the error:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import antlr4
ImportError: No module named 'antlr4'
```

I precise that antlr4 is already present in my computer:

```
$ antlr4
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.5.1
 -o ___              specify output directory where all output is generated
 -lib ___            specify location of grammars, tokens files
...
```

I tryed with 2 little tests too, test.py works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, re, sys
print('test')
```

but this version doesn't:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, re, sys
import antlr4
print('test')
```

How can I connect this antlr4 module with python, please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems it is ok with help on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079258/cant-import-module-antlr-mygrammarlexer-and-mygrammarparser?s=2%7C81.9059).

That content of the package:

https://pypi.python.org/packages/0b/6b/30c5b84d203b62e1412d14622e3bae6273399d79d20f3a24c8145213f610/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.7.tar.gz#md5=190245a0fb4abf43568489a4b6e33aba

is different from the package installed by pip3.

I have replaced content of: .../python3.5/antlr4 with content from the package I have downloaded and extracted manually:

~/Downloads/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.7/src/antlr4

Hope it could help others :)