# Problems with Converting R Code to Python

Tags: python, r, pip, code-conversion

```
from pyensae.languages import r2python

print(r2python(rscript, pep8=True))
```

I have problems converting `filename.R` into `pythonfilename.py` because these libraries are not useful for converting as it generates the error 'module not found' even if I installed that module using:

`pip install pyensae`

Answer (score 6):

The following steps worked for me with the **Python version** `Python 3.7.6`.

1. Upgrade your `pip`

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

2. Install `pyensae` module

```
pip install pyensae
```

3. Check your python console by executing below import

```
from pyensae.languages import r2python
```

If you are facing

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'antlr4'

or facing

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**builtin**'

then execute the below command

```
pip install antlr4-python3-runtime
```

After the above steps, I could able to convert the R script to the python language

```
rscript = """
nb=function(y=1930){
debut=1816
MatDFemale=matrix(D$Female,nrow=111)
colnames(MatDFemale)=(debut+0):198
cly=(y-debut+1):111
deces=diag(MatDFemale[:,cly[cly%in%1:199]])
return(c(B$Female[B$Year==y],deces))}
"""
from pyensae.languages import r2python
print(r2python(rscript, pep8=True))
```

**Console output**

> ANTLR runtime and generated code versions disagree: 4.9.1!=4.8 ANTLR
> runtime and generated code versions disagree: 4.9.1!=4.8 from
> python2r_helper import make_tuple

```
def nb(y=1930):
    debut = 1816
    MatDFemale = matrix(D . Female, nrow=111)
    colnames(MatDFemale) .set(range((debut + 0), 198))
    cly = range((y - debut + 1), 111)
    deces = diag(MatDFemale[:, cly[set(cly) & set(range(1, 199))]])
    return make_tuple(B . Female[B . Year == y], deces)
```

Comment: Suffering with this error !!!!
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined.
Was getting this issue, It has been resolved through restart IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working.

```
from pyensae.languages import rconverter
print(rconverter.r2python(rscript, pep8=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

pyensae is no longer supported with python 2.7

Try `pip3 install pyensae`

Comment: Now this error pops up `   from __builtin__ import unicode

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "__builtin__'' `

Comment: I believe the "builtin" module was renamed to "builtins" in Python 3.

Find the file where the code "from builtin import unicode" is run, and change it to:
"from builtins import unicode"

Source: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/953

Comment: `from builtins import unicode

ImportError: cannot import name 'unicode' from 'builtins' (unknown location)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using:

1. python 3.7.6
2. pip 22.1.2
3. antlr4-python3-runtime 4.9

This answer comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65054963/10987905).

Answer (score 0):

simple you have to decrease pyensae version,

first install below version pyensae

```
pip install pyensae==1.3.825

# you will get autopep8 error, so install autope8 below version

pip install autopep8==1.7.0
```

Then Run below code it will work

```
rscript = """
    nb=function(y=1930){
    debut=1816
    MatDFemale=matrix(D$Female,nrow=111)
    colnames(MatDFemale)=(debut+0):198
    cly=(y-debut+1):111
    deces=diag(MatDFemale[:,cly[cly%in%1:199]])
    return(c(B$Female[B$Year==y],deces))}
"""

from pyensae.languages.rconverter import r2python
print(r2python(rscript, pep8 = True))
```

Output:

```
def nb(y=1930):
    debut = 1816
    MatDFemale = matrix(D . Female, nrow=111)
    colnames(MatDFemale) .set(range((debut + 0), 198))
    cly = range((y - debut + 1), 111)
    deces = diag(MatDFemale[:, cly[set(cly) & set(range(1, 199))]])
    return make_tuple(B . Female[B . Year == y], deces)
```