# How to check if a python class or object is user defined (not a builtin)?

Tags: python, types, module

I need to examine a python module to find simple data as well as "user defined objects".  Here, I mean objects (or functions or classes) that are not builtin, but defined with a class/def statement or dynamically loaded/generated.

Note there are similar questions, but they ask about "new style user defined classes".    I've seen the `inspect` module - I couldn't see how it could help.

I can import a module and 'walk' it, but I don't know an easy way to identify an attribute as a simple type.  eg - how do I tell 0. is a builtin type? here:

```
>>> a=0.
>>> dir(a)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__'...
>>> type(a)
<class 'float'>
```

Do I have to know the classes of all the standard objects to determine if an attribute of a module/object is "user defined"?

Comment: by your logic: when you use any framework they classes are `builtin` or user define?

Comment: Could you give a precise definition of what you want to test for? "User-defined" and "built-in" are much more vague than you may realize.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm asking because the difference is so vague :)  I'd like to walk over everything in bs4 (import bs4) and identify the 'interesting' objects/classes - differentiating the user defined classes under bs4 from classes that are not so interesting like the classes of float attributes in an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try checking if the types module is **builtin**, usually works for me.

For example:

```
a = 1.2
type(a).__module__ == "__builtin__"
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll explore after a snooze.  Thanks!

Comment: Before I nod off, it looks promising - it also works for lists.

Comment: Note that `__builtin__` was renamed to `builtins` in Python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047762

Comment: Since the builtins module name seems to be/have been frequently changed I'd suggest using `type(a).__module__ == object.__module__`