# Why does pysmell installation in vscode produces this error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to install pysmell in vscode but there seem to generate this error whenever i do that. Can someone help me understand and resolve this. Thank you!

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pysmell-script.py", line 33, in <module> 
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pysmell', 'console_scripts', 'pysmell'))
File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pysmell-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pysmell\tags.py", line   17, in <module>
    from pysmell.codefinder import ModuleDict, processFile
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pysmell\codefinder.py", line 13, in <module>
    import __builtin__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

I was following this link (https://code.google.com/archive/p/pysmell/) for the installation process. I have already done `python setup.py install` and `python setup.py develop`. the problem is in the `import pysmell` part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the \_\_builtin\_\_ module in Python3? Why was it renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047745/where-is-the-builtin-module-in-python3-why-was-it-renamed)

Answer (score 2):

Pysmell uses the module `__builtin__`, which was renamed to `builtins` in Python 3. You might have to switch to Python 2, or find a different alternative to Pysmell.

Comment: Can you suggest any other static analysis tool for detecting code smells in python?